# Running several bokeh-server applets against the same server

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

Consider the [sliders](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/server_gallery/sliders_server.html) example in Bokeh. The [documentation](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/sliders_applet) suggests running it as:

1. `bokeh-server --script sliders_app.py`
2. Navigate to    http://localhost:5006/bokeh/sliders

which works great. Note that the script `sliders_app.py` uses `@bokeh_app.route("/bokeh/sliders")` to specify the URL. So far so good.

Now, say I want to instantate a second separate `app`. For simplicity's sake, let's assume it's another sliders example with slightly different code. We save the new app to `sliders_app_2.py`.

I would like to use a different URL (route) for this second app, e.g.`"/bokeh/sliders"`. How can I do this with the same server?

If I just try specifying `@bokeh_app.route("/bokeh/sliders-2/")` for `sliders_app_2.py`, and then run  `bokeh-server --script sliders_app2.py` I run into the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

How can I run several applets against the same server while preserving the ability to specify the route point? Is this at all possible? Can the same server host several apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 0.9.1 we you can create a new `combined.py` that imports all the scripts you would like to load, and pass that `combined.py` as the argument to `--script`. We are working on improvements to allow easier multiple loaded and reloading, etc.